# O365 REST API authorization from Javascript

Tags: ms-office

Running any of the [sample REST API calls for O365](http://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/) works fine with the sand-boxed URLs and authorization headers.

However, substituting these URLs with my own is no-go.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://****-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://****:44301' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Is the issue due to cross-domain scripting?

Extra authorization that must be done on a "real" O365 endpoint as opposed to the sandboxed sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these libraries used from web context ? It sounds like it from the problem description. Please note that these libraries will only work from Cordova app context for now. http://microsoft.response.lithium.com/portal/conversation/1003718

Comment: Yes, this was being called from a web context, I don't recall any mentions of requiring the use of Cordova for O365 APIs... that makes it rather limited. Thanks for the explanation.